# How to use await with hangfire background job?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-2.0, hangfire

I am using hangfire with .net core 2.1. Now the issue is I am using httpclient for making multiple web requests and hangfire doesn't support async methods I think. So the response return before all the web requests are completed. I have commented this line:

```
_backgroundJob.Enqueue(() => EnqueueMyMethodCallBack(email));
```

and used this line:

```
await EnqueueMyMethodCallBack(email)
```

then it was working fine. So is there any way I can await _backgroundJob.Enqueue ? Also I have found this article https://www.hangfire.io/blog/2016/07/16/hangfire-1.6.0.html where it was written that async methods are now supported but I still can't use them.

And the EnqueueMyMethodCallBack method:

```
public async Task<bool> EnqueueMyMethodCallBack(string email)
{
  var response = await _userRepo.GetUser(email);
  if(response == null)
    return false;
  var template = await _template.GetTemplate();
  await _email.Send(template, email);
  return true; 
}
```

Any help?

Comment: "Can't use them"? What happens? There is far from enough information here for us to even attempt to reproduce the problem.

Comment: means it's written in doc that _backgroundJob.Enqueue will handle async methods itself but when I am using _backgroundJob.Enqueue, it's not waiting for all web requests to finish

Comment: Are you sure you're using a version that supports async? How have you verified that it doesn't wait for them all to finish? Perhaps show us the code?

Comment: I have updated my question with the code and I am using latest version of hangfire that is 1.6.19

Comment: Where are the web requests in that code? Is the email being sent? Since you're not using any of the return values from the awaits when constructing the return value of `EnqueueMyMethodCallBack` it will finish running immediatly, and the tasks might get executed during the lifetime of your process. Remove the `return true;` and change return type to just `Task` - hangfire doesn't support any other result than void anyway.

Comment: Have you used a debugger and checked that `response != null`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Enqueue` just adds the job to the queue. The job is executed at a later time, in a different context, even on a potentially different machine (hangfire supports multiple worker machines). It returns the job id so you can query for it later (check status/etc.).

If you want your job to run in that context, call it directly.

So, if the request needs to return something from that job, you don't need a job. There's no point in scheduling a job and awaiting it to finish so you can return something.

Comment: There definitely are use cases for scheduling a job and awaiting it to finish. If I want to run a job in a context and wait for it to return, you say I should call it directly? No, I won't do that, because I want to make use of Hangfire workers and queues. If there's a large amount of jobs queued, calling it directly will skip the queue. That doesn't seem desirable.

Comment: If you don't wait how could you know the job succeeded?

Comment: @Rudey I don't think Hangfire is the right tool to scale your app.